# Consulta a WebService

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2015

Buenas Tardes,tengo los siguientes datos en una tabla en Sql

```
Comprobante Categoria
    603552       A
    624997       A
    651880       A
    672298       C
    615985       C
    613804       C
    617970       A
    625688       A
    689463       B
    611686       B
```

Luego genere una aplicación de consola que consulta al WebService tomando el numero de comprobante y descargando un .pdf, pero me bloquee, esta aplicación tiene que generar una carpeta por Categoria tomando el valor de la consulta sql de la tabla Comprobantes y dentro de cada carpeta descargar la factura correspondiente a esa categoria así quedan ordenadas las facturas por categoria dentro de cada carpeta.
Agradezco toda la ayuda.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = null;
string strSQL = "SELECT numeroComprobante,categoria FROM Comprobantes";

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("********");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var request = new Services.consultarDocumento()
                {
                    request = new Services.requestConsultaDocumento()
                    {

                        numeroComprobante = reader["numeroComprobante"],
                    }

                };

            var address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("*********"));

            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            binding.Name = "basicHttpBinding";
            binding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
            binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;

            var client = new Services.ConsultaDocumentoClient(binding, address);

            var response = client.consultarDocumento(request);

            var Factura= @return.Documento;
            }

            reader.Close();
            con.Close();

    }
  }
```

Comment: te estaria faltando la parte de guardar en la carpeta, o de generar las carpetas?

Comment: Las dos partes me estan faltando gbianchi, descargo el archivo y lo guardo en var Factura= @return.Documento; luego debe de crear la carpeta que le corresponde segun la consulta sql, asi debe de hacer con los otros archivos descargados, cada archivo corresponde a una carpeta, en este caso, descarga el primero, crea la carpeta y lo guarda, pasa al segundo que le corresponde la misma carpeta, ya en el 3 debe de crear otra carpeta B, todo esto segun la consulta sql ya que el orden puede variar. muchas gracias